# Abnormal execute result while using signal in multiprocessing.Pool?

Tags: python, signals, multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing to process many files. In order to handle `ctrl-c` in cmd and quit graceful I add signal to each process.But it is not acting as my expect.

sample code:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool, Value
from time import sleep
import signal, sys

def f(x):
    p = multiprocessing.current_process()

    if exit_flag:
        s = '%s outer exit' %p.name
        sys.stdout.write(str(s)+'\n')
        return

    for i in range(10):
        if exit_flag:
            s = '%s inner exit' %p.name
            sys.stdout.write(str(s)+'\n')
            break
        s = '%s --- %s' % (i, p.name)
        sys.stdout.write(str(s)+'\n')
        sleep(1)

    if exit_flag:
        s = '%s --- %s final exit' % (i, p.name)
        sys.stdout.write(str(s)+'\n')

def handler(signum, frame):
    global exit_flag
    exit_flag = True

def attach_signal_handler():
    global exit_flag
    exit_flag = False
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handler)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # attach to main
    attach_signal_handler()
    # change to size = 2, range(6), make result more readable
    size = 2
    pool = Pool(size, attach_signal_handler)  

    for i in range(6):
        result = pool.apply_async(f, (i,))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    if result.successful():
        print 'successful'
```

When I press `ctrl+c` , it will print something like below.

```
0 --- PoolWorker-1
0 --- PoolWorker-2
1 --- PoolWorker-1
1 --- PoolWorker-2

(press ctrl +c)

PPoolWorker-2 outer exit
oolWorker-1 outer exit
PPoolWorker-2 outer exit
oolWorker-1 outer exit
successful
```

`inner exit` and `final exit` not printed ,why?

what I expect is something like below (order maybe different, just for example):

```
0 --- PoolWorker-1
0 --- PoolWorker-2
1 --- PoolWorker-1
1 --- PoolWorker-2

(press ctrl +c)

PoolWorker-1 inner exit
PoolWorker-1 final exit
PoolWorker-2 inner exit
PoolWorker-2 final exit

(first two processes end at this point)

PoolWorker-2 outer exit
PoolWorker-1 outer exit
PoolWorker-2 outer exit
PoolWorker-1 outer exit

(other four precesses end)    

successful
```

Answer (score 0):

Your other conditions are not evaluated, after you hit the first  "if exit_flag:", because you have return statement, as in this code:

```
    if exit_flag:
        s = '%s outer exit' %p.name
        sys.stdout.write(str(s)+'\n')
        return

    for i in range(10):
        if exit_flag:
            s = '%s inner exit' %p.name
            sys.stdout.write(str(s)+'\n')
            break
        s = '%s --- %s' % (i, p.name)
        sys.stdout.write(str(s)+'\n')
        sleep(1)

    if exit_flag:
        s = '%s --- %s final exit' % (i, p.name)
        sys.stdout.write(str(s)+'\n')
```

You can simply move the return at the end:

```
    if exit_flag:
        s = '%s outer exit' %p.name
        sys.stdout.write(str(s)+'\n')

    for i in range(10):
        if exit_flag:
            s = '%s inner exit' %p.name
            sys.stdout.write(str(s)+'\n')
            break
        s = '%s --- %s' % (i, p.name)
        sys.stdout.write(str(s)+'\n')
        sleep(1)

    if exit_flag:
        s = '%s --- %s final exit' % (i, p.name)
        sys.stdout.write(str(s)+'\n')
    return
```

Comment: if you set size = 2,  range(6), you would see , first two processes do not  print `inner exit` and `final exit`. Tht first two processes have already bypass the first if, so they would not return.

Comment: @Mithril: But some of your processes will exit normally meanwhile, so you will have a snapshot of workers engaged with processes at the moment of "Ctrl+c"

Comment: What do yo mean they will not return? They will reach the end of your function and return. If there is no exit flag they will stop without it? I do not understand what is your objective in your process call.

Comment: It is very clear.First two processes have already bypassed the first `if` which contain `return` and steped into for loop.They must touch other two `if` before end.

Comment: But that is exactly why you put "return" in the end. If a process missed the flag in the beginning, then it should catch the exit flag somewhere in the body. If it does not have the flag will exit normally at the return in the end, without printing any message as your code intends.

Comment: Miss flag? It is impossible,attach_signal_handler have already set `exit_flag = False` at beginning.After a process step into for loop, it check `exit_flag` every loop.Press `ctrl-c` fire signal to change `exit_flag = False`, then the process detect this, print 'inner end' and break from for loop.This is the normal case.I write first `if` to prevent other processes step into for loop after `exit_flag = True`.

Comment: That is what I meant by missed = False. You have two states - True or False. If True, exits with print message, if False, it exits without a print message. Some of your processes will exit with False and therefore you do not see any print output.

Comment: No,in the example on my question, the processes only exit when `exit_flag = True`.Because I press `ctrl-c`, first two processes still in their job(in for loop, range(10) only loop twice at this time) . They do not complete at that time, so they would not return at states `exit_flag = False`!

Comment: Not quite. If it passed the loop and it is still exit_flag != True, then it will exit with False. It does not need to return anything. You can remove all returns to see what happens.

Comment: It can't pass the loop in my example, I have explained that.It would not change when remove all returns.First two process would not print anything.You can set size = 1, range(2), it would be more clear.

Comment: So what it exits with printing "successful", after the second iteration in range(2)... if you do not press any Ctrl+c. Nothing strange. The program finishes as expected.

Comment: I need handle press Ctrl+c in cmd! I have said in title.

Comment: True that! And you have it. In your code simply you can have one evaluation of a type "if exit_flag: print("whatever") return else: return" That would be enough. Obviously the "else" clause is not even needed.

Comment: I just want to solve the problem I meet.My code is OK, even if output is abnormal. I can ignore this , but I want to figure it out.

Comment: Good luck then, lets hope that someone else can help you. Sorry for taking your time.